# Reducing the title spacing

Tags: spacing, lyx

I use LyX. When I use the "Title" environment under article(hebrew), it uses very big spacings between it and the rest of the document. How do I control the spacing and make it use a compact title so my resume will all fit in one page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I would look for a proper resume class, the "quick and dirty" (and non-encouraged) way to reduce vertical spacing is to insert the command \vskip -1.5em after the \maketitle, with 1.5 substituted for an appropriate amount.

Comment: Why would this be non-encouraged? Knuth recognized from the beginning the need to make occasional spacing adjustments in the final version of a document, during the final stages of proofreading. If many similar documents are made, you could make an environment that encapsulates the vskip, but for a single document it's just as easy to insert it directly in the code.

Answer (score 6):

Finding a resume class is definitely the best answer to this question, but for those interested in tweaking the title, I personally like the titling package. I settled on

```
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-6em}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vspace{-5em}}
```

To shift the title up and get rid of some of the white-space underneath it. Credits to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591/removing-vertical-space-inside-maketitle/623#623) answer for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Consider instead using a format or style already defined to produce a resume, there are already lots of useful answers in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae).

Answer (score 0):

when designing your resume, you may not want use all the standard commands. this could become quite tedious.

I assume you want to use \title{} for your resume title *g*

Have you considered inserting a table without border lines. within a table you can select the fontsize and shape yourself and you should have better control over what is going on. To answer you could redefine the \maketitle command...

go to document->settings->latex preamble and copy the marked section in there. for everything with \vskip you could put in another length e.g. \vskip 0.5em instead of \vskip 2em. Also you can alter the font size by e.g. changeing \LARGE to \large

\documentclass{article}
\title{My resume title}

%copy to lynx preamble

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

%up to here

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}